# send all text option in select with request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I use ajax to dynamically populate a drop-down select.

Now i want to send all select option text with my request.

```
<select name=".." >
 <option value="0"> ... </option>
 <option value="1"> xxx </option>
 <option value="2"> yyy </option>   
 ....
</select>
```

i want send in request `xxx` , `yyyy` , ....

Comment: Do you mean that you want to send the texts of *all* options, not just the selected one? If just the selected one, why don’t you simply generate the dropdown so that the text appears as the `value` attribute value or, even simpler, so that you omit the `value` attributes (as they default to `option` element content)?

Comment: no i want all the texts of all options

Comment: what is the use case? this is a very strange request. Why doesn't the value itself work for your needs?

Comment: i have a search form with drop-down select the user choose a first select list and the second select get updated after that the form is submitted and we have the search result with the same criteria that the user choose first to tune his search and i want the data populated dynamically in first form

Comment: Still, it is unclear why you would do that in JavaScript, instead of just inserting, say, a set of hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all text via `JQuery`  `$.map` is probably the most efficient way to do this.

```
var options = $('select option');

var values = $.map(options ,function(option) {
    return option.innerText;
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: but how to send them in a request after a sumbit or with ajax request ?

Comment: just with `$("myform").submit()` after some data check.